# How to make a python script automatically send an email when certain data is changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, gmail

So basically, I made a python script to send me an email containing my public IP every 12 hours. My goal is to make it automatically send an email only when my IP changes. I would love it if you guys could give me some help.

There's my code:

```
from json import loads
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
import smtplib

while True:
    data = loads(urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip").read())
    print ("The public IP is : %s" % data["origin"])

    try:
        server_ssl = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server_ssl.ehlo()

        server_ssl.login("fromemail@gmail.com", "password")
        msg = """From: Automated Python Script <fromemail@gmail.com>
        To: First Last <toemail@gmail.com>
        Subject: SMTP e-mail test

        """ + data["origin"] + """

        """

        server_ssl.sendmail("fromemail@gmail.com", "toemail@gmail.com", msg)

        print ("Successfully sent email!")

        time.sleep(720)

    except SMTPException:
        print ("Something went wrong...")
```

By the way, it's in python 3.

I'd really like it to send me an email automatically when my public ip changes instead of sending me an email with probably the same IP every 12 hours.

Thanks!

Comment: You script sends every 12 minutes not hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks the change in public ip to whichever time interval you want based on the value you set to x. If your public ip changes frequently then set lower values of x and if it changesless often you can set it accordingly

```
from json import loads
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
import smtplib
data_prev = loads(urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip").read())
prev_public = data_prev["origin"]
while True:
    data_next = loads(urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip").read())
    next_public = data_next["origin"]
    print ("The public IP is : %s" % data["origin"])
    if(next_public != prev_public):
        prev_publi = next_public
        try:
            server_ssl = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            server_ssl.ehlo()

            server_ssl.login("fromemail@gmail.com", "password")
            msg = """From: Automated Python Script <fromemail@gmail.com>
            To: First Last <toemail@gmail.com>
            Subject: SMTP e-mail test

            """ + data["origin"] + """

            """

            server_ssl.sendmail("fromemail@gmail.com", "toemail@gmail.com", msg)

            print ("Successfully sent email!")

            time.sleep(x) # set x to whichever value you want
            #time.sleep(720)

        except SMTPException:
            print ("Something went wrong...")
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was searching for. After I posted the question, I continued trying and I came to something close to this. Thank you so much dud!